# C++ read() problems

Tags: c++, io, large-files, ifstream

I'm having trouble reading a large file into my own buffer in C++ in Visual Studio 2010. Below is a snippet of my code where length is the size of the file I'm reading in, bytesRead is set to 0 before this is run, and file is a std::ifstream.

```
    buffer = new char[length];
    while( bytesRead < length ){
        file.read( buffer + bytesRead, length - bytesRead );
        bytesRead += file.gcount();
    }
    file.close();
```

I noticed that gcount() returns 0 at the second read and onwards, meaning that read() did not give me any new characters so this is an infinite loop. I would like to continue to read the rest of the file. I know that the eofbit is set after the first read even though there is more data in the file.

I do not know what I can do to read more. Please help.

Comment: Why don't you check for errors? Why does `gcount` return 0?

Comment: I do know that the eofbit is set, but there is actually more data in the file. I'll add that information to the question.

Comment: Open the file with the second parameter `(std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary)`

Comment: normally std::ifstream::read will try to read "length" chars from the file. so this loop should be executed only once.

Comment: Yousf has a good point. After opening the file as std::ios:binary, it only runs through the loop once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you open your file in binary mode (`std::ios::binary`) to avoid any newline conversions. Using text mode could invalidate your assumption that the length of the file is the number of bytes that you can read from the file.

In any case, it is good practice to examine the state of the stream after the read and stop if there has been an error (rather can continue indefinitely).

Comment: This is actually my problem. I was using file.open( filename ) and after changing it to file.open( filename, std::ios::binary ) it worked fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your stream is in a failed state, at which point most operations will just immediately fail. You'll need to `clear` the stream to continue reading.

Comment: but it's important to know _why_ it's in a failed state.

Comment: @MooingDuck: that depends. In some cases, you *expect* it to go into a failed state (think of writing an imitation of `tail -f`), and checking each time may not be needed. But yes, at least in most cases you probably do. I certainly didn't mean to imply that the *only* thing you'd do was `clear`, only that until you do `clear` it, all further attempts at reading will fail.